# A "What am I" riddle

Tags: riddle

On the one hand, I set something down.

---

On the other hand, I pick something up.

---

(You can probably get *something* out of this!)

---

When there's more than one of me, you could get inside us.

---

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can I stereotype you as a

> drawer

On the one hand, I set something down.

> Your hand may be draw a picture on paper, or a bill of exchange.

On the other hand, I pick something up.

> Your hand may be drawing water from a well, or beer from a keg.

(You can probably get something out of this!)

> A desk drawer.

When there's more than one of me, you could get inside us.

> Long pants!

Comment: Well done, sir.

Comment: @Tom I would not have answered the 4th part quite as you did, but I am guessing maybe this is the British vs. American on that word, so I'll just figure you got the whole thing right.  You certainly hit the answer I had intended.